# Поиск Min и Max в диагоналях матрицы

Tags: delphi, матрицы

Нужно вывести на экран(в консоле) матрицу А(размерность NxN)(числа введены случайным образом)найти первое max на главной диагонали, последнее min на побочной диагонали и поменять их местами

Я немогу найти первое max на главной диагонали, последнее min на побочной диагонали и поменять их местами первая часть кода есть:

```
program Project2;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;
const n=6;
var a:array[1..n] of array[1..n] of integer;
  i,j:integer;
begin
Randomize;
for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to n do a[i,j]:=Random(9)+1;
for i:=1 to n do begin
  for j:=1 to n do
    Write(a[i,j],' ');
    Writeln;
  end;
readln;
end.
```

Comment: Чтобы обойти элементы любой диагонали, нужен цикл for i:=1 to n do.
Элементы a[i,i] будут принадлежать главной диагонали, а a[i,n-i+1] побочной. Если нужно найти первый минимум или максимум, нужен цикл от 1 до n, а если последний, то от n до 1.

Comment: Если последний, можно просто `<` поменять на `<=` =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var imax, nmax: integer;
    imin, nmin, jtmp: integer;
    buf: integer;
{ первое max на главной }
imax := 1;
for i:=1 to n do begin
  if (i=1) then
    nmax := a[i, i];
  if (a[i, i]>nmax) then begin
    imax := i;
    nmax := a[i, i];
    end;
  end;
// nmax = a[imax, imax]

{ первое min на побочной }
imin := 1;
for i:=1 to n do begin
  jtmp := n - i + 1;
  if (i=1) then
    nmin := a[1, jtmp];
  if (a[i, jtmp]<nmin) then begin
    imin := i;
    nmin := a[i, jtmp];
    end;
  end;
// nmin = a[imin, n - imin + 1]

{ меняем местами }
buf := a[imax, imax];
a[imax, imax] := a[imin, n - imin + 1];
a[imin, n - imin + 1] := buf;
```

Вывести хоть сможете?)

**UPD:** Поменять можно и проще, все равно же сохранили(тогда `buf: integer` из переменных можно убрать):

```
a[imax, imax] := nmin;
a[imin, n - imin + 1] := nmax;
```

Comment: я только начинающий и для меня трудно разобраться в этом коде...

Comment: Да вам просто остается вывести матрицу так же как вводили, чтобы результат увидеть. У вас этот кусок уже есть, кстати, в вашем коде)